# How can I solve $x^2y''+2xy'+2y=x$ using VoP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve this differential equation by variation of parameters? If so, how can I compute the complementary solution? Otherwise, how should approach this problem?
$$x^2y''+2xy'+2y=x$$

**My Attempt:**

When I try to substitute $y=x^m$ into the equation I get the characteristic eq. as $m^2+m+2=0$ which gives $m=(−1−\sqrt 7)/2$ and $m=(−1+ \sqrt 7)/2$. Is this correct ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I try to substitute $y=x^m$ into the equation I get the characteristic eq. as $m^2+m+2=0$ which gives $m=\frac{-1-7^{1/2}}{2}$ and $m=\frac{-1+7^{1/2}}{2}$. Is this correct? @Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the homogeneous differential equation:
$$x^2y''+2xy'+2y=0$$
Substitute $y=x^m$:
$$m(m-1)+2m+2=0$$
$$m^2+m+2=0$$
it should give you complex solutions:
$$\Delta =1-8=-7$$
$$\implies m=\dfrac {-1\pm i\sqrt 7}2$$
$$y(x)=\dfrac {\sqrt x}{x}\left(A \cos \left( \dfrac {\sqrt 7}2 \ln x\right)+B 
\sin \left (\dfrac {\sqrt 7}2\ln x \right)\right)$$

---

Note that you have:
$$x^{a+bi}=x^ax^{bi}$$
Now use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$=x^a(e^{bi \ln x})=x^a(\cos( b \ln x)+i\sin (b\ln x))$$
And you also have that:
$$x^{a-bi}=x^a(\cos( b \ln x)-i\sin (b\ln x))$$
Since $\sin (-b)=-\sin (b)$.

Comment: How did you simplify y?

Comment: I  added  some lines @AlineBellangero